# postgres select where value must exist for list of array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am stuck with a query problem in postgres. I need to select all the userids where value must exist for certain array of rules and these rule ids are coming from a subquery.

Here is my table structure:

```
users: {user_id, name, email}
rules: {rule_id, name, description, query}
user_scores: {user_id, rule_id, points}
```

So in the above example I need to find out all the users who has played all the rules.

Actually i wanted to avoid using backend language to loop and check if a user has scores for every rule. I need to fetch all userids from `user_scores` table where all ruleids exists. I am actually looking for IN operation but with AND in nature like

```
select user_id
from user_scores
WHERE rule_id IN (select rule_id from rules)
group by user_id
```

So instead of 'IN' it should work like 'IN for ALL'.. or something like that

Any help will geatly appriciated.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a bit more information about your table structure / what you want to do. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry for not being precise, actually i wanted to avoid using backend language to loop and check if a user has scores for every rule. I need to fetch all userids from user_scores table where all ruleids exists. I am actually looking for IN operation but with AND in nature like
select user_id from user_scores WHERE rule_id IN (select rule_id from rules) group by user_id
So instead of 'IN' it should work like 'IN for ALL'.. or something like that

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result  +

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all users that have a score for all rules, you can use an outer join with `rules`:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name
FROM users AS u
   JOIN user_scores AS us ON u.user_id = us.user_id
   LEFT JOIN rules AS r ON us.rule_id = r.rule_id
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.name
HAVING (count(*) FILTER (WHERE r.rule_id IS NULL)) = 0;
```

I couldn't test it, so there may be some slight errors.